# ¿Es posible ocultar un plugin que está activado del backend de Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Amigos, ¿Es posible ocultar un plugin en Wordpress que está activado del backend?

Que esté activado, sin que nadie pueda ver que está activo.

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agregando este código a `functions.php`  (o a `custom.php` si usas frameworks como Thesis), puedes ocultar un plugin de la lista de plugins instalados.

Ahora bien, si el plugin agrega algún menú de configuración, este código no oculta dicho menú:

```
add_filter('all_plugins', 'ocultar_plugins');

function ocultar_plugins($plugins) {
    $urlPlugin='tablepress/tablepress.php'; //cambiar por url del plugin: carpeta y archivo php
    unset($plugins[$urlPlugin]);
    return $plugins;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como bien comenta @A.Cedano ese código es correcto para filtar el plugin en el listado de plugins.

Para hacerlo en la `AdminBar` tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

```
<?php 
function custom_menu_page_removing() {
    remove_menu_page( $menu_slug );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_menu_page_removing' );
```

Tienes la [función `remove_menu_page` en el Codex de Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page)

De todas formas, en ambos casos, el problema es que aunque la página y las URL se eliminan de la parte de administración, no elimina la posibilidad de que el usuario pueda entrar, esto es, si el usuario conoce la URL de esas páginas puede entrar sin problemas.

Para que esto no ocurra tendrías que hacer el bloqueo a mano. Pero en el mayor de los casos la gente no se conoce las URL, por lo que no tendrías problemas.